# Address of the NSinteger changes by incrementing it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

i am creating a counter in my app. i want to increment it when a particular change has occurred. the counter increments it value from 0 to 1. and then it stucks to 1 and further it does not increment. This is my code. In .h i have done this.

```
@interface URLCacheConnection : NSObject {
  int                     counter;
```

}

and in .m it have

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse self]]) {

    printf("[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields] = %s\n", [[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response suggestedFilename] cStringUsingEncoding: 1]);
    NSDictionary *dict = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
    NSLog(@"allHeaderFields = %@\n", [dict description]);

    if(downloadItem.downloadStatus != DownloadStatus_resumed)
    {
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: downloadItem.fileItem.filePath]) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            NSLog(@"the value of counter is %d", counter);

            NSString * fileExtension = [downloadItem.fileItem.fileName pathExtension];

            NSString *fileName = [downloadItem.fileItem.fileName  stringByDeletingPathExtension];

            fileName = [fileName stringByAppendingFormat:@"-(%d)", counter]; 
            fileName = [fileName stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@",fileExtension]];

            downloadItem.fileItem.fileName  = fileName;

            downloadItem.fileItem.filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", downloadItem.fileItem.folderPath, downloadItem.fileItem.fileName];
        }
        else {
            counter = 0;
        }
        BOOL fileCreatedFlag = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath: downloadItem.fileItem.filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        downloadItem.fileItem.fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: downloadItem.fileItem.filePath];
        fileCreatedFlag = fileCreatedFlag;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: did you mean `NSLog(@"the address of counter is %p", &self.counter);`

Comment: i have remove the @property, but stil it does not work. when i NSLog it for the first time it gives [the address of counter is 0x919e81c] and for the second time it gives [the address of counter is 0x85a8b2c]

Comment: Show **all** of your code, preferably a standalone function or class that we could try ourselves. Right now you're providing only a portion of the code, and people are getting confused trying to guess what you are really doing.

Answer (score 3):

James this is because the `self.counter` will return you a value not the variable so it will print different addresses.
Please give the exact logs and use log as suggested by **Keety** in above comment.

Answer (score 1):

if the download status is resumed then you reset the counter to 0.  If, for arguments sake, each download is resumed at least once, then the counter will always be one when you print it to the log.

Comment: i am using the counter because if same file is downloaded multiple times, so i append the counter value with the file name so that it is saved with another name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSInteger counter = 0;
counter = counter+1;
NSLog(@"the address of counter is %p",counter);
```

Comment: This prints the **value** of `counter`, not its address.

Comment: `NSInteger` is not an Objective-C object. Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW16). You're thinking of `NSNumber`.